# activating constraints programmatically at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I want to change the positions of my view programmatically at runtime using constraints
I have following arrangement of views

```
 |
viewA
 |
viewB
 |
viewC
```

say i have `viewA` with `topAnchor` constraints set to top of margin of parent view and `viewB` with `topAnchor`set to `viewA` and so on for `viewC`

And i want to change the position of these views on certain action at runtime

```
 |
viewA
 |
viewC
 |
viewB
```

i have store two different constraints for `viewB` one with top of `viewA` and another with top of `viewC`

```
viewBTopConstraints = viewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewA.bottomAnchor, constant: TOP_SPACE)

newViewBTopConstraints = viewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewC.bottomAnchor, constant: TOP_SPACE)
```

In my toggle action method i have done something like this

```
viewBTopConstraints?.isActive = false
newViewBTopConstraints?.isActive = true
```

This works on first run of action however it fails on second time, on further debugging in view debugger i found out that it creates duplicate constraints rather that changing the original one.

Comment: You should only modify the `isActive` after the first time.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this kind of behaviour? all i want is to toggle the position of these views based on certain action and since i have created my views programmatically using constraints, i am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements sounds similar to an app where I have some constraints that change based on landscape or portrait. There I set up *three* groups of constraints:

- Those that *always* are `isActive = true`
- Those that are `isActive = true` in portrait
- Those that are `isActive = true` in landscape

The trick is to put the latter two into arrays, and activate/deactive the proper array at the right time. Here's a snippet of what I mean:

```
var p = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var l = [NSLayoutConstraint]()


////// portrait layout....

// pin info button above imageLayout, right justified

p.append(info.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 20.0))
p.append(info.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor))


////// landscape layout....

// pin info button above buttons, right justified

l.append(info.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 20.0))
l.append(info.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor))
```

Note that I'm *not* setting any `isActive = true`. I'm just appending things to the two arrays as needed. Now, in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` - depending on your needs, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` may be the better override - you *activate/deactivate the correct array:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(l)
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(p)
if self.bounds.width > self.bounds.height {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(l)
} else {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(p)
}
```

I've found that working with individual constraints, setting `isActive`, greatly increases the risks of conflicts.